# How do I initialize a new fxml file (with controller) with a button press?

Tags: java, javafx, controller, initialization, fxml

My program is a smart device controller and what it does is that the user will be able to add their own smart devices via this program. (This is a concept program, so as long as the changes reflect in the program, it is good enough)

How would I even go about initialising a new FXML file and its controller by the press of a button, and relflecting the changes in the main controller and fxml?

I am aware that in the context of my project, I would need to create fxml and controller presets. But after that, I do not know how to start making changes to the program through the actions of the elements inside the program.

[This is a basic design of my smart device selection scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5q3R.png)

[This is how my main menu would look like (I manually added these three devices)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJWut.png)

[Lets say I choose to add an air-conditioner from the first image, this is how the changes should reflect in the main scene.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57oNF.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Although you could theoretically write code that modifies your fxml (assuming certain conditions apply), you should not approach the problem this way. Instead a file containing the info to restore the devices should be saved which allows you to restore the data. This way you can implement the logic for showing a list of devices independent of the logic for creating the scene for those devices which reduces complexity and does not require you to output a not-so-simple xml file.

Comment: Assuming that you create all those buttons at the runtime and they are not present in your fxml, you may use `fx:id` tag to make your button container itself (e.g. `Pane`) accessible from your controller.